# RMagick install problem

Tags: imagemagick

I can't install RMagick because of the following dependency problem after trying `sudo apt-get install libmagick9-dev` ([required according to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201689/rmagick-gem-install-cant-find-magick-config)) on Ubuntu 10.0.4:

```
Note, selecting libmagickwand-dev instead of libmagick9-dev Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    libmagickwand-dev:
        Depends: libmagickwand2 (= 7:6.5.7.8-1ubuntu1.1) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libmagickcore2-extra (= 7:6.5.7.8-1ubuntu1.1) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libmagickcore-dev (= 7:6.5.7.8-1ubuntu1.1) but it is not going to be installed
```

Trying to apt-get install libmagickwand2, I get this:

```
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:   libmagickwand2:
> Depends: libice6 (>= 1:1.0.0) but it is not installable
>                   Depends: libjpeg62 but it is not installable
>                   Depends: libmagickcore2 (>= 7:6.5.7.8) but it is not going to be installed
>                   Depends: libsm6 but it is not installable
>                   Depends: libtiff4 but it is not going to be installed
>                   Depends: libxt6 but it is not installable
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This works:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev
```

according to dalibor-filus's comment below.

[*Original answer - Okay I seem to have solved this with `apt-get install imagemagick libmagickwand-dev`, so libmagick9-dev wasn't necessary.*]

Comment: This worked for me. Just want to point out that require 'rmagick' will still not work. You have to use require 'RMagick'.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get: libmagickwand-dev : Depends: libmagickcore-dev (= 8:6.6.0.4-3ubuntu1.2) but it is not going to be installed

Comment: same here... getting this error: https://gist.github.com/4709742

Comment: @TrinitronX @jackocnr you have to first install libmagickcore-dev and then libmagickwand-dev, just got through this on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. (You should be able to install them in one command line, as follows: `sudo apt-get install imagemagick libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev`)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on Ubuntu 11.10, and @mahemoff's solution didn't work for me. In the end I uninstalled everything to do with ImageMagick, and then compiled the latest version of ImageMagick from source, and then rmagick installed just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for OSX: https://github.com/maddox/magick-installer

That worked really well for me where `apt-get` and brew failed

Comment: The software at the link states supported OS: Mac OS X 6 and 7. Please specify if this worked at ubuntu at all.

Comment: Sorry, only tried it on OSX