# error when installing rmagic gem on Ubuntu 12.04 for Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, imagemagick

I am trying to get my Ruby on Rails application working and installing RMagic gem. But I get an error that says "Can't install RMagick 2.13.1. Can't find the ImageMagick library or one of the dependent libraries." Altough I have ImageMagick installed with its dependences.  [image: http://i46.tinypic.com/2vdl1g6.png]

Terminal log : http://pastebin.com/vcgkbwZR

I even tried to installed RMagic from Synaptic, but I get the same error when I run "bundle" command.

Through my search, some people had problem with lib dependencies, but I believed I have them all installed.

Another solution I found is this ( error installing RMagick from gem ) a little bit old and not sure if it is going to work for 12.04. BUT, I don't know where those configurations should go.

Comment: Have you tried this yet? http://askubuntu.com/questions/112548/rmagick-install-problem

Comment: yep, libmagickwand is installed and all ImageMagick dependencies

Answer (score 1):

It is working now and RMagick recognizes where ImageMagick is located after I compiled and installed the latest version of ImageMagick from the main website. I followed the instructions: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php?ImageMagick=9s6tlikqbn5eb0u0spg5o38sa4#unix